# Mod Mono CentOS Install - Dependency: >= httpd 2.2

Tags: centos, httpd, centos5, mono

I've been trying to install Mono on CentOS 5.5 with Cpanel. It was all going fine until I needed to install the mod mono add-on. I get a missing dependency error, any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Tryining to install mod mono:

```
root@ns223540 [~]# yum install mod_mono-addon              
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ovh.net
 * epel: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * extras: mirror.ovh.net
 * updates: mirror.ovh.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod_mono-addon.i386 0:2.10-6.9 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 for package: mod_mono-addon
---> Package mod_mono-addon.x86_64 0:2.10-6.9 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 for package: mod_mono-addon
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mod_mono-addon-2.10-6.9.x86_64 from Mono has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 is needed by package mod_mono-addon-2.10-6.9.x86_64 (Mono)
mod_mono-addon-2.10-6.9.i386 from Mono has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 is needed by package mod_mono-addon-2.10-6.9.i386 (Mono)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 is needed by package mod_mono-addon-2.10-6.9.i386 (Mono)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd >= 2.2 is needed by package mod_mono-addon-2.10-6.9.x86_64 (Mono)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Check httpd verison

```
root@ns223540 [~]# rpm -q httpd              
package httpd is not installed
```

Try to install httpd

```
root@ns223540 [~]# yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ovh.net
 * epel: mirror.ibcp.fr
 * extras: mirror.ovh.net
 * updates: mirror.ovh.net
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use cPanel I think you need to use easyapache. If you still want to use yum then you need to check your /etc/yum.conf if httpd is not listed in the exclude line! Remove it from there and use yum to install httpd